# Android Studio 2.3.3 Logcat "Unable to connect to the editor..." when using emulator; what to do?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

In Android Studio 2.3.3, I get dozens of this Logcat message OFTEN. Probably every 5th run:

```
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
    com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text... will retry later
```

I get no output from `Log.` statements.

Debugging is then greatly hindered.

I am using an emulator 10.1 WXGA Tablet_API_19, Android 4.4.2. But it's happened with other emulators, too. It seems (not positive about this) that this never happens when I connect my Android device to USB and compile app to it.

I restart Logcat repeatedly, I clear it repeatedly, I've even exited Studio; same messages always return.

It's nothing I'm doing is it? One SO Answer about this was, "The error mentioned by you does not belongs specifically to the list view . this is the logcat error. Restart your Logcat hope it will work for you." It doesn't.

So **is there a bug in Logcat**, as another SO comment suggests?

Does anybody who's had this know of a workaround? Should I report this problem as a bug, 'cause it sure ain't right!

Answer (score 1):

According with comment on file code:

> For some reason the app thinks we are not connected to it. This looks like a framework bug... Fall back to ground state and return false. [Link to code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/RichInputConnection.java#264)

What OS do you use?

It's possible that the error is caused by some process in your system or bad config. Try download again Android platform-tools.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I KNOW it's not going to help.  Restart, reformat, reinstall, rehash, repeat, re-diculous.... With all due respect, my experience is this never reliably solves problems. I spend a day reinstalling everything and at the end it won't still happen? Read what you wrote: "Looks like a BUG." And "Fall back" and punt is just a copout. Other people have been having the problem and nobody has a solution. Have you ever noticed all the "It didn't work for me" comments when somebody suggests something like you did? Somebody liked your answer. Not me. Sorry I'm REALLY frustrated.